# ERROR IN ADDING ANOTHER TEMPLATE IN EXISTING APP

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

```
Using the URLconf defined in rldjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='index']
<int:destinations_id [name='destionations']
admin/
accounts/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, destinations.html, didn't match any of these.
```

***"***from  main urls.py******

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('travello.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),

]
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

***from urls.py  travello ***

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('<int:destinations_id', views.destinations, name='destionations')
```

***views.py of travello***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Destination
# Create your views here.
def index(request):


    dests=Destination.objects.all()


    return render(request,"destinations/index.html",{'dests':dests})

def destinations(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

> please tell what i am doing wrong 
>   i am a newbii
>   i am wanting to add one more template to my app index.html is added and i am trying to add destinations.html to it 
>   i am taking tutorials from telesko django course
>   please help

Comment: You forgot to close the angle bracket, so it should be `<int:destination_id>`, not `<int:destination_id`.

Comment: any other mistake it is still not working